# How to downgrade the PHP version 7.2?

Tags: php, perl, payment

I have the PHP and Perl code hosted on Bluehost. It worked well till 3 months ago, but some features don't work recently. I think it is the PHP version problem. I have checked the Bluehost, there is an option to upgrade the PHP version to 8.1, 8.2, no option to downgrade to PHP 7.2. Any suggestions?
Credit card payment feature does not work now, which worked fine 3 months ago. I expect to get it working well as before.

Comment: There are a lot of methods to downgrade your PHP version - although this is the worst option - but even with these methods, you will not be able to do because your are using a shared hosting providers

Comment: `i checked the code and made some changes to get it worked as expect`...so what's the problem then? Or are you saying you didn't manage to get everything working? ` I think it is the PHP version problem`...why specifically? What actual issue are you having? And what happened 3 months ago? Did they upgrade your php version without telling you, or something? The problem us unclear and the solution is both infeasible and possibly based on assumptions. A question with a [mre] of the issue including relevant code and an actual error message would be much more useful to you and to us. Thanks

Comment: Credit Card payment does not work now, it worked fine 3 months ago, So I thought it was the PHP version problem. Please give me the way how to figure it out.

Comment: As I alluded to already, without a clear error message or _specific_ problem description, and a [mre] of that problem, we cannot really help you. "Does not work" could mean anything. We cannot simply guess, without knowing _anything_ about your software. And you still haven't explained what leads you to think the php version has anything to do with it. There is, so far, zero evidence for that in your post. If you do have more info, please [edit] your question rather than posting long comments etc. It makes it clearer for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

PHP 7.2 reached its end of life almost 3 years ago (that is the point in time from which no more security updates are released). Even PHP 8.0 will reach that point pretty soon (in about two weeks from now). That is why Bluehost doesn't offer a downgrade. You shouldn't be using these old versions (in a publicly accessible place, anyways).

See [supported versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) and [migrate](https://www.php.net/eol.php) your code.

Comment: Credit Card payment does not work now, it worked fine 3 months ago, So I thought it was the PHP version problem. Please give me the way how to figure it out.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to check the error logs. If it is a PHP problem, you should find it there.